# How Do I Create A Daily Excel Export In Azure?

Tags: java, azure, architecture, export-to-csv

I am moving a legacy application to the cloud and need guidance on breaking it up.

There is a Java application that creates reports/statements out of a database in PDF, CSV and XLSX. The Excel files are presented to the user on demand and the CSV and PDF files are created each night using a scheduled task. The CSV and PDF files are reports that get sent using SFTP.

Spring JPA and Hibernate extract the data and convert it using OpenCSV and Jasper Reports.

I imagine I could probably just drop all the existing code into an Azure function and use a timer trigger. However, refactoring it to take advantage of other Azure features *seems* like it should be the way to go.

What is the architecture for moving this reporting code to Azure?

Comment: I suppose for lift and shift scenario's you could dockerize your current app and use [azure container instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-overview)

Answer (score 0):

For the above workaround , I do agree with @Peter Bons we can use [***Azure container instances***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-overview) *which is  is an excellent choice for any scenario that requires isolated containers, such as simple applications, task automation, and build tasks.*

For more information please refer this [***BLOG|RUNNING PYTHON SCRIPTS ON AZURE WITH AZURE CONTAINER INSTANCES***](https://kohera.be/tutorials-2/running-python-scripts-on-azure-with-azure-container-instances/)